# How can I get PHP to read my .ldaprc file?

Tags: php, openldap

I am using a system where I do not have write access to the /etc/openldap/ldap.conf file.  Furthermore, I am trying to authenticate against an ldaps:// Active Directory server.  Unfortunately, the key file is unsigned.

Therefore, I need to be able to set the following config parameter to allow PHP to access the LDAP server:

```
TLS_REQCERT allow
```

Can someone tell me how I can debug this, to see why PHP is not using the same setting as ldapsearch?  (ldapsearch works after I insert this setting in my ~/.ldaprc file)

Much appreciated,

Noah

Answer (score 1):

PHP is running as a different user - eg www-data on Debian/Ubuntu. So you need to put .ldaprc in the home directory of that user.

Comment: Actually PHP is running as my users because I have done

--prefix=/home/myuser

Comment: --prefix specifies the location _where_ PHP is, not as what user it's running.

Comment: OK. Try stracing php on the command line like so: `strace -e open php` then `<? $lc=ldap_connect("ldap://server"); ldap_set_option($lc, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3); ldap_bind($lc,'',''); ?>` and see which files it opens. On my system it tries three locations for ldaprc including the local directory.